# How to change a DateTime Format

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
List<DateTime> datetimerange = new List<DateTime>();

DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
foreach (DateTime day in EachDay(StartDate, EndDate))
{
     datetimerange.Add(day.Date);
     Session["SelectedDatess"] = datetimerange;
}
```

When I displays it to a list box the date looks like `8/28/2012 12:00:00` whereas I just want to display `8/28/2012`.

How can I change the format of the date to `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: You can use ToShortDateString method.

Comment: You should format the date where you are displaying it. The code you show does not display the date - could you share that bit of code. As a general answer, you should use a format specifier and perhaps a date-time format string. (PS. two terms that Google easily)

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't have a format. You specify the format at the point where you convert it to a string - in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the [`DateTime.ToString()` Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) Also has a detailed article.

Answer (score 0):

```
Datetime dt=new DateTime();
string date1=dt.toString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Or

```
string _fromDt = DateTime.Parse(txtDateFrom.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

or

string todayDt = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this code :

```
string input = "6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(input);
string output = dt.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",     
                               CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

OR

```
string input = "6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(input);
string output = dt.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy",     
                               CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```